# Server side event - add sleep to script cause message not sending

Tags: javascript, php

I'm building a progress bar when user want export CSV data. Everything works as expected until I want to add a sleep into the while loop.

I tried to use sleep with flush but without success.

Why sleep function is causing message not outputted ?

sse.php

```php
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream; charset=utf-8');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

// perform queries

$lines = $res->rowCount();
$writtenLines = 0;

while ($row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
    writeToCsv($row);
    $writtenLines++;
    sendMsg($writtenLines);
    flush();
    sleep(1);
}

function sendMsg($line) {
    $data = [
        "writtenLines" => $line,
        "totalLines" => $lines
    ];
    echo "data: ".json_encode($data)."\n\n";
}
```

client

```html
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar"></div>
</div>
<br>
<span id="writtenLines">0</span> written lines

<script type="text/javascript">
    var evtSource = new EventSource('sse.php');
    evtSource.onmessage = (e) => {
        const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        updateProgress(data);
        if (data.writtenLines === data.totalLines)
            evtSource.close();
    }

    function updateProgress(data) {
        var p_bar = jQuery(".progress").find(".progress-bar");
        document.getElementById("writtenLines").innerHTML = data.writtenLines;
        status = parseInt(data.writtenLines/data.totalLines * 100);
        p_bar.css("width", status + "%");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What's the goal of sleep? You're going to have to wait `$lines` seconds until the script finishes to get response. Where's the flush?

Comment: You might want to try `rejax.io` (I wrote it) which allows to send messages from server to client by making http post requests to the service API.

Comment: I tried to add flush before sleep. sleep purpose is to test and ensure that progress is updated line by line.